# how to avoid string with certain words before #

Tags: python, regex

I have to find strings doesn't have either of words(as word boundaries) abc, def or ghi anywhere before # using regex in python

**he is abc but # not xyz** -  no match

**he is good # but small** - match

**he might ghi but # not abc will** - no match

**he will help but # hope for def to come** - match

**he is going for vabc but # not sure** - match

This is the list that has strings

```
l=["he is abc but # not xyz",
"he is good # but small",
"he might ghi but # not abc will",
"he will help but # hope for def to come",
"he is going for vabc but # not sure"]
```

It should print

```
["he is good # but small", "he will help but # hope for def to come", "he is going for vabc but # not sure"]
```

Tried using negative lookahead concept in regex with

```bash
^(?!.*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b).*#
```

but couldn't achieve exact result

Comment: You should include your script, if you have one.

Comment: @Cow I have tried using negative look ahead with something like ^(?!.*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b).*# , ^(?!.*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b.*#) but not getting expected output

Comment: Try: `^(?![^#]*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b[^#]*#)[^#]*#.*`

Comment: @anubhava it's working as intended. Add it as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?![^#]*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b)[^#]*#.*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AqU2m2/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?![^#]*\b(?:abc|def|ghi)\b[^#]*#)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if word `abc` or `def` or `ghi` are present before matching a `#` in the match later
- `[^#]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that are not `#`
- `#`: Match a `#`
- `.*`: Match anything afterwards